# Which browser does not support Unicode in URLs?

Tags: browser, operating-systems, web, unicode, url-rewriting

One time, one guy has come to the office and showed me that Polish characters in a website [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)'s path part was percentage-encoded. Currently, I'm looking for browser with similar behaviour for testing, but every recent version I have tested have URL's [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) support. I know only that was [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29), but not if it was Mac or Windows and which version. I have no problems with new Safari on Windows 7.

Which version of which browser on which OS has change characters like `Zażółć gęślą jaźń` typed in address bar to something like `Za%C5%BC%C3%B3%C5%82%C4%87%20g%C4%99%C5%9Bl%C4%85%20ja%C5%BA%C5%84`?

You can check it by pasting this `http://www.google.com/Zażółć%20gęślą%20jaźń/` to the address bar and watching how it's changed. The 404 error information is not my interest.

Comment: Can't you just test each browser, I mean honestly, there is what 5 different browsers even worth a dime that are stand-alone engines.  Certainly this would be based on the operating systems support for unicode and its polish language support.

Comment: I was tested each recent browser: Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE9. I have not mac. If you don't understand my question, please dont answer.

Comment: It's just presentation, and internally it's still urlencoded, especially when you copy&paste it.

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested only in visually change in the address bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16) requires percent-encoding of Unicode characters in URLs:

> When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual data consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set, the data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8 character encoding; then only those octets that do not correspond to characters in the unreserved set should be percent-encoded.  For example, the character A would be represented as `A`, the character LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE would be represented as `%C3%80`, and the character KATAKANA LETTER A would be represented as `%E3%82%A2`.

Even though this applies to new URI schemes, most current browsers will perform percent encoding on URLs.

Comment: It's clear. I'm abandon language-specific chars in my urls. Maybe in the future...

Comment: I forget to mention. Safari 5 on Windows has terrible bug when you trying to assign polish letters (as above) by javascript's to location object.